# Getting current URL from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, request

I need to check the referrer from inside an iframe.  If accessing the page via the bookmark, I cannot do this. Instead I grab the URL, with client side javascript as I cannot get the masked URL with server side requests.

Now I have the URL in clietn side javascript - how do I feed it into my server side code execution on the first page load?

Is there a much simpler way of getting the current URL in the address bar, from inside an iframe?

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: have you tried accessing the document using `top`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) to exchange data between client and server without refreshing the page.

To do the Ajax request only on the first page load, you could combine sessions with cookies:

1. Check server side if the sessions
   variable **not_first_page_load** is
   already set. If it's not set it
   means it is the first page load:
   create a cookie **first_page_load**
   and after that set the sessions
   variable, so that forthcoming
   requests won't trigger this any more.
2. On the client side you should
   check for the cookie
   **first_page_load**. If you find it, then
   you should make the Ajax
   request.
3. Back on the server side, where 
   you handle the Ajax request, you
   should remove the cookie
   **first_page_load**.

Comment: I understand how to handle when the AJAX request fires. My Question now is how do I assign my client side URL value to the server side code, in the AJAX code, before it finishes loading the page?

Comment: Well, the Ajax request is made after the page is loading. If you need to have some custom content displayed on the page, you could get that content through Ajax and then use Javascript to insert that content in the DOM. Please provide more details if my comment is not helping you, because I don't know what you want to achieve server-side with that URL value.